# How to programatically monitor resources (CPU, RAM,DISK) of remote linux server?

Tags: php, monitoring

I would like to create script that will monitor resources(CPU,RAM,DISK) on remote linux servers (client servers).
What would be the best way to access these parameters remotely ?

I would prefer something based on PHP. I don't need ready-to-use solution, I need to create it myself as I need possibility for customization.

Client side script/program must be easy to configure/install.

Comment: Have you looked at nagios? It still allows for quite some customization.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a Java application called the remote-linux-monitor. You can find the source at https://github.com/dbothwell/remote-linux-monitor . If you study the code you will find techniques for calculating CPU and memory load. I hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you just need pointers, you'll need to parse `/proc/cpuinfo`, `/proc/meminfo` and `/proc/diskstats`. These contain real time data exported by the kernel.

Comment: Yes, but what if the remote server is not mine, I mean I need it to work on client servers. And the most important part for me is how to make the client side as easy to install/configure as possible

Comment: Why can't you do this on remote servers?

Comment: This is a service and client will need to install "something" on own machines to make me possible to get data and display them in my web interface for them... the important part is that "something"

Comment: This will be the web service, so I don't know who'll join ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hey sorry for late reply. I have written this program in PHP that will show you the CPU and RAM usage stats of your server.

You can check it out here - http://code.google.com/p/php-cpu-monitor/

I know you said you're not really looking for a completed solution but it is quite simple and I've documented it all so it would be easy to modify.

Hope this helps,

Steve